# I want to access to user id in functions.php in custom hook

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using "store file uploads for contact form 7" plugin. this plugin returned attachment id by following hook:

```
function example_callback_id_generated($attachment_id)
{
return attachment_id;
}

add_action('nmr_create_attachment_id_generated', 'example_callback_id_generated', 10, 1);
```

I want to get current user id in this function to attach file upload to the user by following code:

```
function example_callback_id_generated($attachment_id)
{
update_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'ownership_document', $attachment_id);
}

add_action('nmr_create_attachment_id_generated', 'example_callback_id_generated', 10, 1);
```

but current user id always is 0

I used get_current_user_id(); in functions.php but I always get 0;

Please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Accord to documentation:

get_current_user_id(): int

Gets the current user’s ID.
The current user's ID, **or 0 if no user is logged in.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).